# Docker virtual network adapter not added to docker0 bridge

Tags: docker

Everytime I try to start any container in bridged network mode, the virtual network adapter is not added to the docker0 bridge. As a result, these containers don't have access to the network. I see the docker0 bridge and vethXXXXXX@ifXXX virtual interface from `ip addr`. However, `brctl show` shows the docker0 bridge with no interface attached. I can manually add the interface using `brctl addif vethXXXXXX docker0` and everything works fine.
Some containers exit so quickly due to the connection problem that I don't have a chance to add them before they get a new virtual interface when restarting.
I already deleted all the docker network adapter and let them reinitialize by restarting docker, without success.
Does anybody know how I can fix this, so that network interfaces of container get automatically added to the docker0 bridge on startup?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use networkctl to check veth status.

```
networkctl status -a
```

It might match incorrect network setting. You can use another higher priority systemd-networkd setting to correct it.

ex:
Create a new file /etc/systemd/network/20-docker-veth.network
with content

```
[Match]
Name=veth*
Driver=veth

[Link]
Unmanaged=true
```

and restart the systemd-networkd service.

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd.service
```

Then, start a new container with bridge network would auto link to veth.

ref: https://forums.docker.com/t/archlinux-container-veth-interfaces-being-assigned-to-wrong-bridge/107197/2